# How to write 'WHERE' clause condition with AND in joomla 1.7? I have no data save for update

Tags: mysql, database, joomla

Please suggest how to write the following `UPDATE` query with `AND` in joomla.

Code:

```
$query = JFactory::getDbo()->getQuery(true);
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query->update('table1');
$query->set('id = ' . $db->quote($idname));
$query->set ('day='. $db->quote($this->_day));
$query->set('id2 = ' . $id2);

$query->where('id = '. (int)$idname)
        AND('id2=' .(int)$id2 );
```

The update is unsuccessful and the error is something like this:

```
//........[something before ]....

array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "id = '1'"
    [1]=>
    string(14) "id2='2'"
    [2]=>
    string(17) "date = 2012-04-02"    [it seems i got all the value pass to be update]
  }
  ["glue:protected"]=>
  string(4) "
, "
}
["where:protected"]=>
object(JDatabaseQueryElement)#251 (3) {
  ["name:protected"]=>
  string(5) "WHERE"
  ["elements:protected"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "id = 2"  [where clause is ok  ...BUT with AND...]
  }
  ["glue:protected"]=>   
  string(5) " AND "
}
["group:protected"]=>  [something is wrong here...?]
NULL
["having:protected"]=>
NULL
["columns:protected"]=>
NULL
["values:protected"]=>
NULL
["order:protected"]=>
NULL
["autoIncrementField:protected"]=>
NULL
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure about Joomla update query but I think its something like this:-

```
$query->where('id = '. (int)$idname);
$query->AND('id2=' .(int)$id2 );
```

or:-

```
$query->where('id = '. (int)$idname . 'AND id2 = '.(int)$id2);
```

Comment: I try '$query->where('id = '. (int)$idname . 'AND id2 = '.(int)$id2);
' and it works through. thankssss! FYI , i don't know why the first one gives me the error that i miss sqli param'

Answer (score 6):

You should use

```
$query->where('id = '. (int)$idname, 'AND')
      ->where('id2=' .(int)$id2 );
```